# When writing a post to people you don't know, which form of address should you use: 'tú', 'usted', or 'ustedes'?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, formalidad, escritura, ustedeo

When writing a post to people you don't know, which form of address should you use: "tú," "usted," or "ustedes?"

Primero mi pregunta en español:

**Al escribir un post a la gente que no conoce, ¿cuál forma de dirigirse debería usar?**

**Details in English**

I've always been taught that it is polite to start off with "usted" when you first meet someone and wait for their permission to "tutear" them.  I tend to practice that rule, but it seems a bit stiff, formal, and perhaps rude to continue with "usted" rather than drop to "tú."  When you are face to face, voice to voice, or even text to text with someone, it's easier to pick up on the social cues that help you determine which to use.

When writing a post to an unseen audience, however, I am always wondering which form I should use.  In the past, I've tended to adopt the Wikipedia style which uses the "ustedes" form.  However, the better my Spanish gets, the more awkward it feels to use the "ustedes" form in my posts because I am imagining a single individual reading my post and not a whole room full of people.  Granted, when you post something online, millions could potentially see your post and several hundred of them at the same time even, but it isn't quite like standing in front of a group of people and addressing them all at once.

**What is a good rule of thumb to use when deciding which form of address to use in a post and is it necessary to stick with the same form throughout the post?**  More specifically, is it acceptable to use just the "usted" form and then switch to the "ustedes" form in the last paragraph?  For example, let's say you've been discussing some aspect of English in a post and you've been using the "usted" form.  You finish writing your main points and you want to end with, "If any of you (using "ustedes" here) have any contributions to make to this post, please add them (again using the "ustedes" form here) in the comments section below."  Is it perfectly acceptable to end it like this or would this be considered a poor or uneducated writing style?  If I end it with something like that, must I use "ustedes" throughout the post?

Also, if there is some sort of usage book or other authoritative source that prescribes rules for this, please share that information with us also.

As always, thanks in advance for your time and attention to this question.

**Detalles en español**

Siempre me han enseñado que es cortés empezar con «usted» en el primer encuentro con alguien y esperar para su permiso a «tutear».  Tiendo a practicar esa regla, pero parece un poco rígido, formal, y quizás maleducado continuar con «usted» más que bajar a «tú».  Cuando estás cara a cara, voz a voz, o aún texto a texto con alguien, es más fácil de recoger señales sociales que puede ayudar a determinar cuál de ellas usar.

Al escribir un post a un público invisible, sin embargo, siempre me pregunto qué forma debería usar.  En el pasado, he tendido a adoptar el estilo de Wikipedia que usa la forma de «ustedes».  No obstante, cuanto mejor es mi español, más incómodo me resulta usar la forma de «ustedes» en mis posts porque me estoy imaginando una sola persona leyendo mi post y no un cuarto lleno de gente.  Concedido, cuando se cuelga un post en línea, millones potencialmente podría ver su post y aún cientos de ellos al mismo tiempo, pero no es exactamente como estar parado delante de un grupo de gente y abordarlos de repente.

**¿Cuál es una buena regla general para decidir cuál forma de dirigirse es la mejor al escribir un "post"?**  Y, ¿es necesario seguir con la misma forma a lo largo del post?  Más específicamente, ¿es aceptable usar sólo la forma de «usted» y luego cambiar a la forma de «ustedes» en el último párrafo?  Por ejemplo, digamos que se ha estado discutiendo algún aspecto del inglés en un post y se ha estado usando la forma de «usted».  Acaba de terminar sus puntos principales y quiere terminar con, «Si alguno de ustedes tienen alguna contribución que hacer a este post, por favor añádanlas en la sección de comentarios abajo».  ¿Es perfectamente aceptable terminarlo como esto?  O, ¿sería un pobre estilo de escritura, o quizás inculto?  Si lo termino con algo como eso, ¿tengo que usar «ustedes» en todas partes del post?

También, si hay algún tipo de libro de uso u otra fuente autorizada que prescriba normas para esto, por favor, además compártanlos conmigo.

Como siempre, gracias de antemano por su tiempo y atención a esta pregunta.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @guifa.  Aquí en este sitio siempre veo *tú*.  Me acuerdo, en un periodo de mi aprendizaje, estaba dudando mucho de la cuestión de Ud-tú, y un amigo me comentó que el cariño y el respeto en el trato son más importantes que el pronombre que uno escoja.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En la Web, por omisión yo diría que debes tutear o vosear a menos que haya una razón para tratar de usted (situación o texto formal, por ejemplo).  Eso probablemente se debe a las formas de tratamiento en los países hispanohablantes que más usuarios tenían en los albores del Internet (seguramente si hubiesen sido todos costarricenses, la cosa habría acabado diferente).

No hay problema en cambiar de singular a plural si te diriges al final a más de una persona, es lo mismo de cambiar en inglés de *you* a *y'all*.  Ten en cuenta que si empleas el castellano peninsular o africano, normalmente vas a mantener el nivel de formalidad (es decir, si en singular usabas *tú*, usarás *vosotros* en plural, si *usted* en singular, *ustedes* en plural).

Comment: Gracias, @guifa.  Esto va a hacer todo mucho más fácil en el futuro.

Comment: Personalmente, creo que ni con Costa Rica estrenando Internet usaríamos el usted en España jaja. Somos muy tozudos, véase el caso de los doblajes. Sencillamente nos suena tan extraño y forzado que crearíamos un "protocolo propio".

Comment: @FGSUZ Jaja es más que posible que tengas razón. A mí me cuesta mazo usar el usted.

Answer (score 1):

Esto depende un poco de cada país, no es lo mismo en todos los países de habla hispana. En Argentina es muy común usar el "vos" (tu), por ejemplo los niños tratan a los adultos de "vos" (tu). Esto no está muy bien visto en otros países de centroamérica.

En resumidas cuentas, para una web sobre temas generales, yo usaría el "tu". Si es una web que apunta a temas más formales, probablemente sea mejor usar el "usted". Sobre el plural no veo problema en usar "ustedes", pero tu frase si bien está bien escrita, se siente un poquito... no se, forzada. Yo pondría:

> "Si tienes alguna contribución que hacer a este post, por favor añádelas en la sección de comentarios de abajo"

o en la forma de "usted" sería

> "Si tiene alguna contribución que hacer a este post, por favor añádala en la sección de comentarios de abajo"

Comment: No soy argentino ni voseante, pero creo que estaría bien que los voseantes empujen más su forma de hablar.  Ayudaría, creo, a los voseantes centroamericanos que se encuentran perjudicados por su forma de hablar que los tuteantes de la zona vean cada vez más voseo, así normalizándoles la forma (como ya es, obviamente, en la Argentina y el Uruguay entre algunos otros).